# Два тире или две запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Не было никаких сомнений в том, что соперник Алексея поручик Карташов (?)  сердцеед и, казалось, не ведающий страха бретёр, только и ждущий повода для дуэли (?) тоже будет на балу.

Comment: СПАСИБО ВСЕМ ЗА ОТВЕТЫ!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Не было никаких сомнений в том, что соперник Алексея поручик Карташов - сердцеед и, казалось, не ведающий страха бретёр, только и ждущий повода для дуэли, - тоже будет на балу.*

Необходимы два тире. Запятые не справляются с интонационным рисунком предложения.   Тире помогут выбрать нужную интонацию и выделить распространённое обособленное приложение, внутри которого есть запятые, выделяющие вводное слово и причастный оборот.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Я бы поставил два тире: уж больно выпадает эта характеристика персонажа из общего построения фразы, откидывая сказуемое в самый конец - почти как в немецком или японском. Без этого можно даже принять её за перечисление других гостей, и тогда только долгожданный глагол, оказавшись в форме единственного числа, заставит вернуться к переосмыслению прочитанного.

Answer (score 1):

Это уж как ваша душенька захочет. Выбор знака здесь - дело сугубо авторское. Мне лично фраза не кажется распространенной настолько, чтобы претендовать на тире. Впрочем, я в подобных случаях вообще больше ориентируюсь не столько на распространенность, сколько на самостоятельность значения обособляемого фрагмента. Но тут и достаточной самостоятельности я не наблюдаю. Не смею настаивать, это моё личное восприятие данного правила.